# SAS Macro using multiple lists for conditions

Tags: sas

I have a condition table that I want to use to create my other tables. Now I want my code to go through my condition table taking into consideration both condition. My data looks as follow.

```
 Month    Date1     Date2     Line  
 Jan2010  01Jan2010 31Jan2010 PL  
 Feb2010  01Feb2010 28Feb2010 CB
 Feb2010  01Feb2010 28Feb2010 HB
 Mar2010  01Mar2010 31Mar2010 PL
```

Current Code

```
  %Macro Split_Data(Month,BeginDate,EndDate,Line);  
  Data Want_&Month._&Line.;  
    Set Have;  
    Where Date > &BeginDate and Date <&EndDate and Line = '&Line.';  
  Quit;
  %Mend;  
  %Split_Data(Jan2010,'01JAN2010'd,'31JAN2010'd,PL);  
  %Split_Data(Jan2010,'01JAN2010'd,'31JAN2010'd,CB);
```

I don't want to list the macro like this. I would much rather have a table the macro calls up and condition on. Is this possible? How can I create a less manual method. So I can update my condition table without having to update my SAS code.

Comment: Why are you making separate datasets?  Why not just merge and use the new LINE variable?

Comment: Call Execute allows you to call the macro from the data set parameters. Look at the example in the documentation.

Comment: @Tom I need the data as input for other software I use.

Comment: @Reeza I have read through the documents I used call execute using one list. But don't know how to expand it to multiple list. <<data _null_;
    set have;
    call execute ("%Split_Data("||Line||");");
run;>>. Would like to include BeginDate and EndDate as well.

Comment: Use the data step to make a string that looks exactly like your macro call, I use CATT to concatenate the string together. Basically, you can concatenate them in as well. Also, use single quotes so the macro doesn't try to execute.

Comment: @Reeza Thank you. Used the code and it work. Will definitely play around with all this new knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dates could complicate things. That being said, you can pass the SAS date values across without quotation marks and your macro would still work. If you have other area's that use the date you would have to confirm that it met your requirements. I would usually use a `data _null_` step but I saved it to a data set WANT here so you can see the string, if desired.

```
data want;
set have;

    str = catt('%split_data(', put(month, yymon7.), ",", date1, ",", date2, ",", line, ");");

call execute(str);
run;
```

Comment: I have used this code. My actual macro is actually a couple of datasteps. How do I condition that should the table have no entries to not show errors in fro example datastep 2....10? Hope is makes sense. Otherwise I will post another question

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No worries.  I thought of something I will try tomorrow, if it doesn't work I will post a new question. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use your metadata to generate the code you need.

First set some macro variables (or make a macro with parameters).

```
%let inds=HAVE;
%let base=WANT ;
%let metadata=METADATA;
```

Then use the metadata to generate a single data step to write all of the output datasets.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set &metadata end=eof;
  file code ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'DATA';
  dsname= catx('_',symget('base'),month,line);
  put @2 dsname ;
  if eof then put ';' / @2 "set &inds;" ;
run;

data _null_;
  set &metadata end=eof;
  file code mod;
  dsname= catx('_',symget('base'),month,line);
  put @2 'IF date > "' date1 date9. '"d and date < "' date2 date9. '"d and line=' line :$quote.
         'then output ' dsname ';'
  ;
  if eof then put 'run;' ;
run;
```

Then include the generated code to run it.

```
%inc code / source2 ;
```

So for your example the generated code would look like this:

```
DATA
 WANT_Jan2010_PL
 WANT_Feb2010_CB
 WANT_Feb2010_HB
 WANT_Mar2010_PL
;
 set HAVE;
 IF date > "01JAN2010"d and date < "31JAN2010"d and line="PL" then output WANT_Jan2010_PL ;
 IF date > "01FEB2010"d and date < "28FEB2010"d and line="CB" then output WANT_Feb2010_CB ;
 IF date > "01FEB2010"d and date < "28FEB2010"d and line="HB" then output WANT_Feb2010_HB ;
 IF date > "01MAR2010"d and date < "31MAR2010"d and line="PL" then output WANT_Mar2010_PL ;
run;
```

Comment: thank you. Will definitely keep this code in mind. I am learning a lot with all of you helping me